# C# MVVM взаимодействие моделей

Tags: c#, mvvm

Как по паттерну MVVM модели могут обмениваться информацией друг с другом?? Я читал, что с случае с view-model необходимо ставить MVVM Light Toolkit и юзать Messanger. С моделями точно так же??

Comment: Приведите пример, пока не понятно что вы имеете ввиду. Обычно модель пассивна. И уж точно она не должна зависеть от UI. В идеале модель это отдельная библиотека, например, которую можно подключить как к дестопному приложению, так и к консольному или вообще к веб-приложению. Было бы странно, если она за собой тянет кусок GUI-фреймворка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модели не должны обмениваться данными сами. Они только хранят данные либо обрабатывают (преобразовывают) свои данные. Обменом занимаются либо вью-модели либо классы бизнес логики.
Обмен может происходить явно либо если они реализуют интерфейсы `INotifyPropertyChanged` или `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: Значит я плохо понимаю суть MVVM. Предположим я хочу по данному паттерну запилить приложение, которые бы следовало за другим окном. Получаю координаты чужого окна с помощью WinAPI, проверка координат чужого окна должна происходить у скажем каждые 0.1 с. Разумеется проверка координат должна проходить в другом потоке. ВОПРОС! Где должен быть расположен метод проверки координат чужого окна?? в модели, VM или вообще в другом классе?? Каким образом данный метод должен передавать координаты чужого окна в свойство нашей модели, которая передает их в VM, а та в свою очередь view, через binding????

Comment: Как сказал бы Андрей Акиньшин - "Зависит" =)

Comment: Мне кажется, стоит логику слежения реализовать в отдельном классе. Создавать экземпляр или получать его через конструктор view-model. View-model от него должна как-то получать данные - это может быть `Event` или `ReactivePrperty` или опрос по таймеру. При получении данных вы их складываете в соотвествующие Property view-model'и, на которые забинжена View. Тут единственный вопрос, в том, что насколько получится таким способом забиндить позицию окна - не разу не было необходимости делать такого на WPF. Возможно, придется делать это через CodeBehind.

Comment: Уже получилось, без codebehind. Спасибо большое.